# SQL where clause case

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT     
*
FROM  tbl_Something
WHERE 
RoleID = 1 AND 
GroupID = 
    CASE
        WHEN @GroupID = 1 THEN @GroupID OR GroupID IS NULL -- issue here
        WHEN @GroupID = 2 THEN @GroupID
```

What I want to do is 
when @GroupID = 2 then GroupID = @GroupID meaning get all the rows with groupID = 2 
when @GroupID == 1 then GroupID = @GroupID or GroupID IS NULL meaning gets all rows with GroupID = 1 or GroupID IS NULL

Where am i going wrong

Comment: Wouldn't you want to check if @GroupID falls within a valid range of values before you even run the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split up the condition, because `OR GroupID IS NULL` cannot be part of an expression that selects a `GroupID` for comparison. Since you have only two possibilities for `@GroupID`, it would be cleaner to rewrite your query without `CASE` altogether:

```
SELECT     
*
FROM  tbl_Something
WHERE 
RoleID = 1 AND (
    (@GroupID = 1 AND GroupID = 1)
    OR
    (@GroupID = 2 AND (GroupID = 2 OR GroupID IS NULL))
)
```

Comment: @paqogomez That's because the question has been edited several times. It's been 1, then 2, and now it is 1 again. I have not changed it back to 1, because I think OP would get the idea either way.

Comment: yes. there was a discussion with the team. 1 and 2 kept changing. Sorry i should not have updated. the concept still remains the same. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNULL` for this. 
It will test if `GroupId` is equal to `@GroupId`, if `GroupId` is null it will check if 1 is equal to `@GroupID`

```
ISNULL(GroupID,2) = @GroupID
```

Comment: Sorry. The Just unpaded my the lead req changed

Answer (score 1):

Use Coalesece, or IsNull:

```
WHEN Coalesce(@GroupID, 1) = 1 THEN 1
```

Additionally, notice that when you are testing for 1, its easier to read if you just return 1.

Answer (score 1):

Why using `CASE WHEN` at all when you can do this:

```
SELECT     
    *
FROM
    tbl_Something
WHERE 
    RoleID = 1 AND 
    ISNULL(GroupID, 1) = @GroupID
```

... unless you need to make sure the query must not return anything if `@GroupID` is anything else than 1 or 2, in which case the following would be far better:

```
IF @GroupId IN (1, 2)
BEGIN
    SELECT     
        *
    FROM
        tbl_Something
    WHERE 
        RoleID = 1 AND 
        ISNULL(GroupID, 1) = @GroupID
END
```